# $\mathbb{Z}$ is Euclidean domain

Tags: ring-theory

It is well known that $\mathbb{Z}$ is Euclidean domain. But when my teacher asked me to prove it, I went towards Peano Axioms for natural numbers, or integers.

**Question:** How can we **prove** that $\mathbb{Z}$ is Euclidean domain?

---

If this is not correct question, I will withdraw it. Sorry!

Comment: It is proved [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Actually, it is proven here. It is the same proof as I given below. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is the following proof which use the axiom that any non-truvual subset of the natural numbers contain aminimal element.

Let $a,b\neq 0 \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then there exist $q,0\leq r<|b|$ (and unique), such that
$$a=bq+r.$$

You define the following set 
$$W=\{a-bq\geq 0:\quad q\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$
It is easy to show that $W$ is non-empty and hence have aminimal element which we call $r$. It is easy to prove from here the uniqeness.

Comment: The third line in your argument, is it not the use of Euclidean domain property?

Comment: @Groups He's not using it, he's stating what he wants to prove. He proves it below, saying that $r$ is the minimal element of $W$.

Comment: @Groups , look at Arthur answer.

Comment: @Groups The answer should not omit the key step, namely why minimality of $\,r\,$ implies that $\,0\le r < |b|,\,$. *Conceptually,* this is because $W$ is *closed under subtraction by* $b$ (when $> 0),$ so if $\,r \ge |b|\,$ then $\,r > r-b\in W\,$  contra minimality of $\,r.\,$ Intuitively the induction amounts to adding or subtracting $\,b\,$ from $\,a\,$ until we land in the interval $\,[0,b)\ \ $